# Swift and Socket.io: Event doesn't run anymore when re-open a controller

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, swift, socket.io

I'm beginner Swift and Socket.io. The socket.io library for Swift that I'm using is https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift

For using 1 socket.io connection in a multiple controllers, I use Singleton with below code in Singleton_SocketManager.swift:

```
import Foundation

class Singleton_SocketManager {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton_SocketManager()
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:3000")
    var currentController = ""
    var loadedHander = [String: Bool]()
    var currentRoomId = 0

    init() {
        loadedHander["ViewController"] = false
        loadedHander["NextViewController"] = false
    }
}

let sharedSocket = Singleton_SocketManager()
```

To add event handler in each controller, I call addHandlers() function in viewDidLoad() and the code of addHandlers() like that:

For ViewController:

```
func addHandlers() {
    if (sharedSocket.loadedHander["ViewController"]!) {
        return;
    } else {
        sharedSocket.loadedHander["ViewController"] = true
    }

    sharedSocket.socket.on("eventInViewController1") {[weak self] data, ack in
        println("View Controller: Event 1")
    }
}
```

For NextViewController:

```
func addHandlers() {
    if (sharedSocket.loadedHander["NextViewController"]!) {
        return;
    } else {
        sharedSocket.loadedHander["NextViewController"] = true
    }

    sharedSocket.socket.on("eventInNextViewController1") {[weak self] data, ack in
        println("NextViewController: Event 1")
    }
}
```

They run fine in first time. But if I have to change controller with this code:

```
let storyBoard = self.storyboard
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as! NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

and go back to ViewController with the same code, the old event handler will not run. I know I can run it by remove the code of checking and marking "sharedSocket.loadedHander" but if I do like that, all events will run twice, and triple if I go NextViewController and back to ViewController again.

I tried to research a lot about this issue but can't find any solutions for this. If you work with Swift or Objective-C and Socket.io library before and resolved this issue, please help me.

Thank you very much for your reading!

Answer (score 1):

Try to disconnect from the first ViewController before performing the segue to the next ViewController. Then, reconnect in the second ViewController.

In addition, you might want declare the `socket` constant globally.